# Accessing the web from a MVVM Light ViewModel in design mode on WP8

Tags: c#, mvvm, windows-phone-8, mvvm-light

I am using the MVVM Light framework with the MVVM ViewModelLocator and have a method as follows:

```
protected override System.Threading.Tasks.Task<string> GetFromUri(string uriString)
{
    string outString;

    TaskCompletionSource<string> tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<string>();

    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(new Uri(uriString, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
    request.Method = "GET";
    request.BeginGetResponse((result) =>
    {
        WebResponse response = request.EndGetResponse(result);
        using (var inStream = response.GetResponseStream())
        {
            long length = inStream.Length;
            byte[] inBytes = new byte[length];
            inStream.Read(inBytes, 0, (int)length);
            outString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(inBytes, 0, (int)length);
            tcs.TrySetResult(outString);
        }
    }
    , null);

    return tcs.Task;
}
```

...which I am trying to use in "design mode". It seems that the best place to call this is within a

```
if (IsInDesignModeStatic)
{
    //....
}
```

in the ViewModel's constructor. However, it fails with a "cross thread" exception. Wrapping the call in a Dispatcher.Invoke for the Application.Current.RootVisual gets us past the "cross thread" exception, but results in a "Cannot access a disposed object" instead (referencing the dispatcher object).

Using the MVVM Light framework on Windows Phone 8, can you perform a web request in design mode (I can't see any technical reason why not)? If the ViewModel constructor is the wrong place to do this, what would be the right place?

Comment: Quick solution--assume Debug is design mode, use `#if DEBUG` directive to cordon off all code that breaks in design mode.  Other solution--save the result elsewhere, set it from the UI thread once.  Fin... er, last solution--dispatch the call, cache the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue originated from using HttpWebRequest. Rewriting to use HttpClient (System.Net.Http library available on NuGet) solved the problem.